# VerifyException in moveTo() method

Tags: java, rinsim

My vehicles will move around randomly when they have nothing to do and look for new jobs, but sometimes, right before they would collide the following exception is raised:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" com.google.common.base.VerifyException:  [(14.11111111111111,0.0), (16.0,0.0), -0.36111111111111116]
    at com.google.common.base.Verify.verify(Verify.java:462)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.computeTravelableDistance(CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.java:138)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.GraphRoadModelImpl.doFollowPath(GraphRoadModelImpl.java:178)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.doFollowPath(CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl.java:82)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.AbstractRoadModel.moveTo(AbstractRoadModel.java:133)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.road.AbstractRoadModel.moveTo(AbstractRoadModel.java:102)
    at project.agents.AgvAgent.movementTick(AgvAgent.java:281)
    at project.agents.AgvAgent.tickImpl(AgvAgent.java:213)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.pdp.Vehicle.tick(Vehicle.java:55)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.TimeModel.tickImpl(TimeModel.java:139)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.SimulatedTimeModel.doStart(SimulatedTimeModel.java:32)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.core.model.time.TimeModel.start(TimeModel.java:94)
    at com.github.rinde.rinsim.ui.SimulationViewer$5.run(SimulationViewer.java:401)
```

Here is the code for moving to the destination (part of the tickImpl method) and for choosing a new destination and path:

```
CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl model = (CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl) getRoadModel();

if (!randomDestination.isPresent()) {
    nextRandomDestination(model);
}

getRoadModel().moveTo(this, randomDestination.get(), time);

if (model.getPosition(this).equals(randomDestination.get())) {
    nextRandomDestination(model);
}

void nextRandomDestination(CollisionGraphRoadModelImpl model) {
    randomDestination = Optional.of(model.getRandomPosition(rng));

    Point end = randomDestination.get();
    Point start = model.getPosition(this);
    if (model.getConnection(this).isPresent()) {
          start = model.getConnection(this).get().to();
    }

    randomPath = new LinkedList<>(model.getShortestPathTo(start, end));
  }
```

I tried moving to the point as well as following the path with `RoadModel.followPath()`. I also copied some code from `AgvAgent` and `AgvExample` classes, but even though it works for them it did not work in my case. I did find some comments in `GraphRoadModelImpl.doFollowPath()` about some bugs. I'm wondering if there are any workarounds for this? Or is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Can you post some code (i.e. a minimal working example) that demonstrates the problem you describe?

Comment: Here is a minimal working example: https://github.com/DamianSzkuat/rinsin_VerifyException 
Running main should produce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out there was a bug in RinSim related to a rounding error that caused this behavior. This bug is fixed as of [RinSim v4.4.6](https://github.com/rinde/RinSim/releases/tag/v4.4.6).